# How to use variable as key when using loops in handlebars.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js

In handlebars I have an array of strings and an array of objects. I want to loop through the array of objects, and then for each iteration I want to loop through the array of strings, and then print the current object element at index [current string] of the string array.

```
                      '{{#each data}}'
                         '{{#each fields}}'
                              '{{{../[this]}}}'
                          '{{/each}}'
                      '{{/each}}'
```

`data` is the array of objects and `fields` is the array of strings.
How can I access the object element from `data` and get the value with the key that is the current element in `fields`?

Thanks

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#lookup